# PHP mysql query return wrong result

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["stjel"])) {
        if($_POST["type"] == "Penger") {
            $luck = rand(1,4);
            $randuser = $sql->query("SELECT brukernavn FROM `brukere` WHERE `level`='1' AND `liv`>='0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
            $randbruker = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `brukernavn`='$randuser'");
            $target = mysql_fetch_object($randbruker);
            $hvormyefra = $target->hand * 0.15; 
            $amount = $targed->hand - $hvormyefra;
            if($luck == 1) {
                echo"<div class=\"velykkett\">You stoled $amount from";
                echo $randuser;
                echo"</div>";
            } else {
                echo"You failed to steal money!";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

all that `$randuser` return is `Resource id #39`
i need ut to return a random `brukernavn` and not `Resource id #39`, how can i fix this? since now this is messing up my code

Comment: `query` function returns resource. From which you can fetch what you need.

Comment: @u_mulder is there another way i can do this? / How can i fetch the resource ive tryed but it only gives me Resource id #39

Comment: You've already wrote `$target = mysql_fetch_object($randbruker);`. Don't you think that you should do the same with `$randuser`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should fetch and store results in another variable. $randuser will always return resource id. Moreover, you do not need to write two separate queries to fetch all information of a random user.
Try removing both queries and write only this one.

```
  SELECT * FROM `brukere` WHERE `level`='1' AND `liv`>='0' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

This query will pick a random user and return all data regarding it.